# How to close materialize multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, drop-down-menu, materialize

On IOS (both tablet and iphone) there is no way to close materialize mutliple select, because it doesn't close neither if you click out of the select nor any of options.

http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select

My question is:

- Is there a way to close select dropdown when clicking anywhere out of the select?
- If not - what else user can do to close the select?

Comment: I guess it is working just like how you expect it to work (in that example URL that you have provided)..

Comment: It's not. Did you open it with iPad or Iphone?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem.

There is an open issue with an answer that helped me.

> The tap out is only reacting to click events which doesn't seem to be
>   fired on iPad/iPhone. This seems to work if you add a touchstart event
>   handler or "redirect" touchstart to click (that is, fire a click event
>   on touchstart events).

Source : https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2319